# Mex function - Lemma 23

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

We have $\operatorname{mex} S=\min \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \notin S\}$ and $a \oplus b=\operatorname{mex}\{x \oplus b ; a \oplus y, \forall x, y \in \mathbb{N}: x<a, y<b\}$. Prove that
$$\operatorname{mex}\left\{d, c \oplus z, \forall z<a \oplus b\right\}=\operatorname{mex}\left\{d, c \oplus\left(x \oplus b\right), c \oplus\left(a \oplus y\right),\forall x<a,y<b\right\}.$$
I attempted to prove it using induction but was unsuccessful. Upon further reading, I found it in lemma 23 of the document below
[enter link description here](https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/27904/1/bMATH_2022_TielmanBB.pdf.pdf)
However, when the author states "At the same time we know that all values for $x^{\prime} \oplus y$ and $x \oplus y$ bigger than $x \oplus y$ yield different values when added to $z$, so that means that we must have equality", I don't understand why the equation holds.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $a\oplus b$, it seems to be circular.

Comment: That is the recursive definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what they are trying to prove is false. To see this, let $a=b=1$, and let $c=d=0$.

$$
\newcommand{\t}{\oplus}
\newcommand{\mex}{\operatorname{mex}}
\mex\left\{d, c \oplus z\mid z<a \oplus b\right\}=\mex\{0,0\oplus z\mid z<0\}=\mex\{0\}=1,
\\\,\\\text{but}\\\,\\
\operatorname{mex}\left\{d, c \oplus\left(x \oplus b\right), c \oplus\left(a \oplus y\right)\mid x<a,y<b\right\}
\\=\mex\{0,0\oplus (x\oplus 1),0\oplus (1\oplus y)\mid x<1,y<1\}\\=\mex \{0,1\}=2.
$$

---

Here is what you can prove, which allows you to prove that $\oplus$ is associative.

> **Lemma:** Let $a,b\in \mathbb N$. Let $A,B\subseteq \mathbb N$ be sets such that $\mex A=a$ and $\mex B=b$. Then
> $$
> a\oplus b=\mex\{a^*\oplus b,a\oplus b^* \mid a^*\in A,b^*\in B\}
> $$

*Proof:* Since $\{0,1,\dots,a-1\}\subseteq A$ and $\{0,1,\dots,b-1\}\subseteq B$, we have
$$
\{a'\oplus b,a\oplus b'\mid a'<a,b'<b\} \subseteq \{a^*\oplus b,a\oplus b^* \mid a^*\in A,b^*\in B\}
$$
This implies that the $\mex$ of the left hand set is at most the $\mex$ of the right hand set. The mex of the LHS is $a\oplus b$, by definition, so we have proved $$a\oplus b\le \mex \{a^*\oplus b,a\oplus b^* \mid a^*\in A,b^*\in B\}.$$To prove the reverse inequality, note that since $a^*\neq a$ for all $a^*\in A$, and $b^*\neq b$ for all $b^*\in B$, we have that
$$
a^*\oplus b\neq a\oplus b \qquad \text{and} \qquad a\oplus b^*\neq a \oplus b
$$
This shows that $a\oplus b\notin \{a^*\oplus b,a\oplus b^* \mid a^*\in A,b^*\in B\}$, which implies that $a\oplus b\ge \mex \{a^*\oplus b,a\oplus b^* \mid a^*\in A,b^*\in B\}$. (Since $a\oplus b$ is an excluded element, it is at least as big as the **m**inimum **ex**cluded element).$\tag*{$\square$}$

The authors made the mistake of trying to turn this Lemma into a more general statement, but in the process they made it false.

> **Theorem:** $\oplus$ is associative.

*Proof:* Let $x,y,z\in \mathbb N$. In the first equality below, we apply the Lemma, with $a=x,b=y\t z$, $A=\{0,1,\dots,x-1\}$, and $B=\{y'\t z,y\t z' \mid y'<y, z'<z\}$.  In the last equality, we again apply the Lemma. For the middle equality, we inductively apply associativity.
$$
\begin{align}
x\t (y\t z)
&=\mex\{x'\t (y\t z),x\t (y'\t z),x\t (y\t z')\mid x'<x, y'<y, z'<z \}
\\
&=\mex\{(x'\t y)\t z,(x\t y')\t z,(x\t y)\t z'\mid x'<x, y'<y, z'<z \}
\\
&= (x\t y)\t z. 
\end{align}
$$$\tag*{$\square$}$

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!